# Two different ssh config options to connect to the same remote host

Tags: ssh, remote-access, hpc, singularity-container

I am trying to get a somewhat convoluted SSH setup working. There is a remote HPC cluster that spins up compute nodes that one can access through SSH. There are hundreds of nodes with names like `cluster1a2345`. Each time I spin one up, I get a random node, so I'd like to be able to define one SSH config rule to cover every node: `cluster*`

In addition, I would love to have the option to run a Singularity container through a `RemoteCommand` (required to use VS Code remotely). I'd like to have these as two separate login options:

1. Run something like `ssh cluster1a2345` to log into a particular node without Singularity
2. Run something like `ssh singularity~cluster1a2345` to log into the node and run Singularity

Also, in order to connect to `cluster*`, I have to ProxyJump through a login node called `login_node`.

I could achieve option (1) alone with

```
Host login_node
    HostName <login node URL>
    User <username>

Host cluster*
    Hostname %h
    ProxyJump login_node
    User <username>
```

Or option (2) alone with

```
Host login_node
    HostName <login node URL>
    User <username>

Host cluster*
    Hostname %h
    ProxyJump login_node
    User <username>
    RemoteCommand singularity shell /path/to/.sif
```

But is there a way for me to have both options available at the same time, as desired? Extracting the true hostname from something like `ssh singularity~cluster1a2345` seems to be the sticking point.